# SQL query - dealing with Null Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table

```
Name   Amount Paid  
-----------------------
Ali      500    500  
Baba     700    100  
Cam      300    Null   
Dave     Null   Null
```

I want the following desired result:

```
Name   Amount Paid  
--------------------
Baba     700    100  
Cam     300    Null
```

I wrote the following SQL query but it did not work

```
SELECT Name, Amount, Paid  
FROM Table_1  
WHERE PAID <> AMOUNT
```

Comment: What did you get? Error or some result different from your expected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work if you treat `NULL` as Zero *(assuming that is valid business logic)*:

```
SELECT Name,  ISNULL(Amount,0), ISNULL(Paid,0) as Paid
FROM   Table_1  
WHERE  ISNULL(Paid,0)  <> ISNULL(Amount,0)
```

Comment: This would produce an invalid result when `Paid` is zero and the `Amount` is `NULL`, or vice verse.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hence my opening line asking if NULLs could be treated as Zeros, have clarified the opening line to my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `null <> null` is `null`, and `null = null` is also `null`, resulting in a false condition. Confusing?

You have to check for null separately, using the `is null` operator:

```
select
 Name, Amount, Paid
from Table_1
where 
 (Paid is not null and Amount is not null and Paid <> Amount) 
 or 
 not (Paid is null and Amount is null);
```

Or, in some cases, you can easily use

```
coalesce(Paid, 0) <> coalesce(Amount, 0)
```

Comment: False! The result of `null <> null` is not false, it's null

Comment: @JakubKania It's a false condition in a where clause. MS SQL doesn't have true or false.

Comment: But still it is null not false. If you're gonna use it as a part of other experession like `NOT null <> null` you still get null. The where clause is not true an that we could agree on.

Comment: @JakubKania Okay, I have modified my answer to make this clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT    Name, Amount, Paid  
FROM     Table_1  
WHERE ISNULL(PAID,0) <> ISNULL(AMOUNT,0)
```

Comment: This would produce an invalid result when `Paid` is zero and the `Amount` is `NULL`, or vice verse.

Comment: Right you are, I assumed he would never insert a 0/null combo.  Thank you for identifying.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT    Name, Amount, ISNULL(Paid,0) as Paid
FROM     Table_1
WHERE ISNULL(Paid,0)  <> AMOUNT

Comment: This would produce an invalid result when `Paid` is NULL and the `Amount` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

NULL means unknown, so the dmbs cannot say that 300 <> NULL. Use Coalesce(col,0) when NULL means zero:

```
SELECT Name, Amount, Paid  
FROM Table_1  
WHERE COALESCE(PAID,0) <> COALESCE(AMOUNT,0)
```

Comment: This would produce an invalid result when `Paid` is zero and the `Amount` is `NULL`, or vice verse.

Comment: It seems that NULL indicates here that nothing is paid or nothing is to be paid. Same as zero. So the result will show all records that are over- or underpaid.

Comment: If `NULL` and zero are the same, the table could be changed to prohibit `NULL`s. The main point of allowing `NULL`s in the first place is to have a way of saying "we don't know". Assuming that the author of the question made the right decision on this one, treating `NULL`s as zeros would be incorrect. Of course the only person to decide if this is right or wrong would be the designer of the table.

Comment: NULL doesn't have to mean "we don't know". It can mean "nothing". For instance: 1. I give someone a present. The amount to pay is zero. 2. I've never given anything to someone. There is yet no amount for them to pay (NULL). But this is usually such a subtle difference, that one wouldn't model it in your database. You see from the request that haroon doesn't want to get the NULL/NULL record. If it were an unknown amount to be paid and an unknown amount already paid, we would have wanted this in the result list, I guess. True, very likely these should be non-nullable columns defaulting to 0.